# How to implement OWIN bearer token based authentication without using Identity?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

I need to implement angularjs Single page application role based authentication using OWIN bearer token and JWT. But i have separate web service to check the user available or not and also get the user roles.

There for i need to generate bearer token by using that rest resource results without using Identity database.